# Force re-layout on a viewgroup including all its children

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I am writing up a custom layout (which extends `FrameLayout`) that can be zoomed in. All its children are also custom views which would actually get the scale factor from their parent via a getter method and scale accordingly by setting the scaled dimensions like

```
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    float scaleFactor = ((CustomLayout) getParent()).getCurrentScale();
    setMeasuredDimension((int) (getMeasuredWidth() * scaleFactor), (int) (getMeasuredHeight() * scaleFactor));
}
```

I am using a `ScaleGestureDetector` to detect the "pinch to zoom" gesture and change the layout's scaleFactor. Then I force a layout on the custom layout by calling `requestLayout`. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to have any effect on its children. The children's `onMeasure` & `onLayout` are never called even though the parent goes through its measure & layout cycle. But, if I directly call `requestLayout` on one of the children, just that child gets scaled according to the scale factor set in the parent!!

It seems that unless `requestLayout` is exclusively called on a view, it doesn't actually measure itself again and instead uses some kind of cache. This is evident from the source code for view which says

```
if (mAttachInfo != null && mAttachInfo.mViewRequestingLayout == null) {
        // Only trigger request-during-layout logic if this is the view requesting it,
        // not the views in its parent hierarchy
        ViewRootImpl viewRoot = getViewRootImpl();
        if (viewRoot != null && viewRoot.isInLayout()) {
            if (!viewRoot.requestLayoutDuringLayout(this)) {
                return;
            }
        }
        mAttachInfo.mViewRequestingLayout = this;
    }
```

How do I force the children also to go measure themselves again on calling `requestLayout` on their parent?

Answer (score 7):

This will force relayout the view's children (given that view's own width and height does not need to change)

```
private static void relayoutChildren(View view) {
    view.measure(
        View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(view.getMeasuredWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
        View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(view.getMeasuredHeight(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
    view.layout(view.getLeft(), view.getTop(), view.getRight(), view.getBottom());
}
```